# How do you solve this Haskell problem using a fold map and take?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Define a function replicate which given a list of numbers returns a 
list with each number duplicated its value.  Use a fold, map, and take

..> replicate [5,1,3,2,8,1,2]

output: [5,5,5,5,5,1,3,3,3,2,2,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,1,2,2]

I've figure this out using List comprehension and recursion:

```
replicate2 [] = []
replicate2 (n:nn) = take n(repeat n) ++ replicate2 nn
```

but how would you use fold and map to do this?
so far I have: replicate n = map (foldl1 (take n(repeat n)) n) n
which is obviously wrong, but I think I am close..

so any help would be nice, THANKS!

Comment: Wow - all four of your questions start "How do you solve this" and are all homework.  Please put more effort into understanding the problem and asking a subset question that will clarify your understanding about some broader aspect (of Haskell).

Comment: alrite, i'll take your advice. thanks

Comment: you may consider adding the "do-my-homework-you-suckers" tag as well. people on SO are good people that like to help out. but they don't like to spend more effort on your problems than you're willing to spend on them yourself

Comment: a search phrase describing this technique is "run length encoding"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key in Haskell is always *follow the types*:

```
foldr  :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a)      -> [a] -> a
map    :: (a -> b)           -> [a] -> [b]
take   :: Int                -> [a] -> [a]
```

I've added some spaces here to make it a bit more clear how these three functions compare. Remember when you look at these that a type variable, `a` or `b`, can match *any* type, including things like `String`, or `[Float]`, or even `[(String,[Int])]`. For example, in the expression:

```
foldr (\a b -> product a + b) (0::Int) [[1,2,4],[5,2],[0,3,6]]
```

`foldr` is being used as type `([Int] -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> [[Int]] -> Int`. That is `a` has matched `[Int]` and `b` has matched `Int`.

**Now:** Think about at the "outermost" level what your expression has to do. Which of these functions fits that form?

Can you cast your problem into an outer expression that has one of these forms and an "inner" problem?

Answer (score 2):

You've got your function application order mixed up. 
Think about what you need to be able to do:

1. Turn a number `n` into a list of `n` copies of itself
2. Apply operation #1 on every number in a list
3. Concatenate all the lists you got from #2 together.

You know how to do 1: `take n $ repeat n`
Of 2 and 3, which is a `map` and which is a `fold`?

Step 2. is a `map` - you're *mapping* ("transforming") every item in the list, into a list.
Step 3. is a `fold`, since you're *aggregating* ("flattening") a bunch of list elements into one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, 2 is fold and 3 is map. But I cant seem to get take n repeat n to take in an Int, because something like 
foldl1 (take $ repeat) [2,2]
does not work.
I was thinking to use foldl1 to evaluate each of the list using take $ repeat then use map to get it all together. but how can I use take and fold together?

Comment: I think 2 is map and 3 is fold.

Comment: Yep, it's the other way around - I've updated my answer a bit more..

Answer (score 1):

```
replicate2 lst = concatMap(\x ->  (take x) (repeat x)) lst
```

Comment: You can also use `Control.Applicative`. `concatMap (take <*> repeat)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
replicate xs = foldl (++) [] (map (\n->take n $ repeat n) xs)
```

The idea is map on every element of a list which just repeats an element x , x number of times. Then fold on the list to concatenate it. Suppose the list is [5,1,2]

So `(map (\n->take n $ repeat n) xs)` is [[5,5,5,5,5],[1],[2,2]]
and then you just have to concatenate the inner lists.